# unable to set up send-email function as desired

Tags: powershell, outlook

I'm attempting to create a `Send-Email` function in a script which can change the email address each time the script is used. However, I'm currently suck being forced to use a static email:

```
function Send-Email (
    $recipientEmail = "EMAIL",
    $subject = "Ticket" + $type,
    $body
) {
    $outlook = New-Object -ComObject  Outlook.Application
    $mail = $outlook.CreateItem(0)
    $mail.Recipients.Add("EMAIL")
    $mail.Subject = ("Ticket - " + $type)
    $mail.Body = $body   # For HTML encoded emails
    $mail.Send()
    Write-Host "Email sent!"
}
```

I'd like to set it up so that I can define `$recipientEmail` and then later use this input with `$mail.Recipients.Add("EMAIL")` - I've beend doing `$mail.Recipients.Add("$receipientemail")` and the like without any luck and wondering if I'm approaching this completely wrong?

I'd like it to be set up in a way that it could use

```
[void] $listBox.Items.Add("Email1")
[void] $listBox.Items.Add("Email2")
[void] $listBox.Items.Add("Email3")
```

And accept that as the email to send to instead of only working with one email.

Comment: Why can't you use `$mail.Recipients.Add("$recipientEmail")`?

Comment: Anything wrong with simply using the builtin `Send-MailMessage` cmdlet? If you must roll your own, your problem is most likely that you're trying to add multiple recipients. You need to add recipients one at a time: `$recipientEmail | ForEach-Object {$mail.Recipients.Add($_)}`.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin when using that the output is There must be at least one name or contact group in the To, Cc, or Bcc box.
At C:\...\test1.ps1:146 char:1
+ $mail.Recipients.Add("$recipientEmail")

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I'm only trying to add the one email, i'm going to set it up so that it'll be selecting from a list to only use 1 email, I don't want it to use multiple - right now i'm using one of the actual email address however when trying to change it to a $receipientEmail it suddenly doesn't believe it has a stored value while being defined above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This whole thing rang a bell with me, and I went "code dumpster diving". I wrote this same function (more or less) a year ago. I'm not using `$mail.recipients.add()`; I'm using `$Mail.To = $RecipientEmail`; if I want multiple recipients, I simply `-join ";"` them and assign to `$mail.To`. The members `$mail.CC` and `$mail.BCC` work the same way:

```
Function Send-Email { 
<#
.Synopsis
    Sends Email using Microsoft Outlook
.DESCRIPTION
    This cmdlet sends Email using the Outlook component of a locally-installed
    Microsoft Office. It is not expected to work with the "Click-to-run" versions.
    This version requires that Outlook be running before using the cmdlet.
.PARAMETER To
    Must be a quoted string or string array, may not be omitted.
    Specifies the address to send the message to. If an array, it will
    be converted to a semicolon-delimited string. May contain contact 
    groups.
.PARAMETER Subject
    Must be a quoted string, may not be omitted.
    Specifies the subject of the message to be sent.
.PARAMETER Body
    Must be a string or a string array, may not be omitted.
    Contains the text of the message to be sent. If supplied as a string in double 
    quotes, any PowerShell variables will be expanded unless the leading $ is 
    escaped. If supplied in a script via a variable containing a here-doc, will 
    reproduce the here-doc. If supplied as an array, either by variable or by the 
    Get-Content cmdlet, the array elements will be joined with `r`n as "separators". 
    A body supplied via Get-Content will not have expanded variables; arrays created 
    in scripts using double quotes or via here-docs willl have expanded variables.
.PARAMETER CC
    Must be a quoted string or string array, may be omitted.
    Specifies an address to send a copy of the message to. If an array, it will be
    converted to a semicolon-delimited string. All recipients can see that a copy 
    of the message was sent to the addresses here.
.PARAMETER BCC
    Must be a quoted string or string array, may be omitted.
    Specifies an address to send a copy of the message to. If an array, it will be 
    converted to a semicolon-delimited string. The recipients named here are not 
    displayed as a recipient of the message, even though they do receive the message.
.PARAMETER Attachments
    Must be a quoted string or string array, may be omitted.
    Specifies one or more files to be included with the message as attachments.
.INPUTS
   This version of the cmdlet does not accept input from the pipeline
.OUTPUTS
   No output to the pipeline is generated. The cmdlet does return an error code.
.EXAMPLE
    Send-Email -To "boss@example.com" -Subject "Personnel Issue - John M. Ployee" -Body "I need a raise."

        Sends an email with the indicated subject and body to the stated address.
.EXAMPLE
    $messagebody = @"
    Roses are red
    Violets are blue
    I need a raise
    And so do you
    "@

    $others = "boss-of-boss@example.com","hr@example.com"

    Send-Email -To "boss@example.com" -Subject "Personnel Issue - John M. Ployee" -cc $others -Body $messagebody

        Sends an email with the indicated subject to the stated address. The body 
        will be composed of the lines in the variable $messagebody as shown; the 
        line breaks are preserved. A copy of the message is sent to the two addresses
        listed in $others.
.EXAMPLE
    Send-Email -To "boss@example.com" -Subject "Personnel Issue - John M. Ployee" -Body (Get-Content -Path "C:\Request-for-raise.txt")

        Sends an email with the indicated subject and body to the stated address.
        The body is drawn from the indicated file, and line breaks are preserved.
.EXAMPLE
    Send-Email -To "boss@example.com" -Subject "Personnel Issue - John M. Ployee" -Body "Please see attached for rationale for raise" -Attachments (Get-Content -Path "C:\Request-for-raise.txt")

        Sends an email with the indicated subject and body to the stated address.
        The indicated file is included as an attachment.
.NOTES
    Planned Future Enhancements:
        1. Allow the cmdlet to accept input (message body text) from the pipe.
        2. Allow the cmdlet to accept the body from a file (parameter -BodyFromFile)
        3. Allow the cmdlet to start up Outlook if it is not already running.
           This includes shutting it down afterward.
        4. Allow the body to be formatted as HTML or RTF, and properly handle this.
           Initially, switches (e.g., -BodyAsHTML or -BodyAsRTF); better would be to
           use file name (e.g., -BodyFromFile "C:\Test.html" would still set the message
           format to HTML even in the absence of -BodyAsHTML); best would be to inspect
           content of file.

        Based on a script from http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_function_send_email.htm
#>

    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [String[]]$To,

        [String[]]$CC,

        [String[]]$BCC,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [String]$Subject,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [String[]]$Body,

        [String[]]$Attachments
    )

    Begin {
        # Future Enhancement: Start Outlook if it's not already running
    } # End of initialization

    Process {
        # Create an instance Microsoft Outlook
        $Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
        # Create a new mail message
        $Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
        # Set up the email
        $Mail.To = $To -join ";"
        if ($CC -ne $null) {
            $Mail.CC = $CC -join ";"
        }
        if ($bcc -ne $null) {
            $Mail.BCC = $BCC -join ";"
        }
        $Mail.Subject = "$Subject"
        $Mail.Body = $Body -join "`r`n"
        if ($attachments -ne $null) {
            foreach ($Attachment in $Attachments) {
                $silencer = $Mail.Attachments.Add($Attachment)
            }
        }
        # I need to investigate scripting Outlook more.
        # The next three comments may be all that's needed
        #   to handle HTML and/or attachments.

        # $Mail.HTMLBody = "When is swimming?"
        # $File = "D:\CP\timetable.pdf"
        # $Mail.Attachments.Add($File)

        # Place message in outbox.
        $Mail.Send()
    } # End of Process section

    End {
        # Clean up after ourselves. This prevents Outlook from reporting
        #   an error on exit.
        [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Outlook)
        $Outlook = $null

        # If Outlook settings are to Send/Receive only on command rather
        #   than as-needed, force the send at this time.
        # NOTE TO SELF: CHECK THIS!
        # $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI").SendAndReceive(1) 

        # If we launched Outlook at the beginning, close it here.
        # $Outlook.Quit()
    } # End of End section!
} # End of function
<#

Note 2: Look in Outlook's outbox for a newly-created message.  

Note 3: If you really want to send the email then append this command:
$Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI").SendAndReceive(1) 
#>
```

Comment: I've changed over to use this which did actually remove one of the issues I was having however it's prompted another issue "We need to know who to send this to. Make sure you enter at least one name.
At C:\.....\test1.ps1:149 char:1
+ $mail.Send()"

Comment: aha! this is actually ideal, it seems that if i move my $recipientemail down it'll work, I don't know why this is the case but it's like once it's been given a value it throws it away during the second part but making it take the value in the second part makes it work fine.

Comment: FWIW, I made this more-or-less compatible with the built-in `Send-MailMessage`, to allow minimal changes to scripts that use the latter, when an SMTP server wasn't available.